# New to ABAP GUI Programming - what to learn?

Tags: user-interface, abap, dynpro, webdynpro

I am new to ABAP programming. To prepare myself for my new job, I am reading ABAP books. During reading, I learned that ABAP has several legacy elements to keep it backwards compatible with older SAP releases.

Regarding GUIs, I am reading about SAP-UI (PARAMETERS, etc.) Dynpros and WebDynpros. Now, I am unsure about on what to focus my learning efforts on.

Are the common rules like "You should know a little about basic SAP-UI, but mainly focus on WebDypros."

Background information: My new employee does SAP customizing for small and medium sized enterprises.

Comment: Obviously, you will need to know whatever is required by your new job. The size and nature of the businness is of secondary importance, if of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a consultant, but I work for a medium (~120 employees) sized company myself. If you were to work for us you would mostly create custom abap reports, maybe sometimes program a user exit. Small companies usually don't spend the money needed for big SAP driven portals, so they probably don't use Netweaver AS Java at all. That means abap dynpro and abap lists as your main UI elements. Sometimes it is good to also know your way around other ways of creating reports, for instance SAP Query.

If I were you I would start with basic abap. You won't have any fun working with dynpros if you haven't gotten your head around the basic stuff first. Learn to work with internal tables, work areas, field symbols. Have a look at some basic ABAP Objects stuff (for instance the ALV grid, very useful for displaying all sorts of tables). You should also understand the ABAP Dictionary, the place where structures, tables, data elements, data domains ans search helps are defined.